# Node.js and Socket.io - cannot read property 'sockets of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm still quite new to node.js and hope you can help me.

I use Node (v7.9.0) with the modules express (4.15.2) and socket.io (1.7.3) to create a simple webserver and send events from the webserver to the connected client.

I'm trying to modularize my application and would like to emit different event to client on different js files.

Now this is my current code:

--- start.js:

```
// Configure the build-in webserver
var 
  express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  server = require('http').createServer(app),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
  conf = require('./serverConfig.json');

module.exports = server;            // Export to use with uart_functions.js

module.exports.io = io;             // Export to use with uart_functions.js

server.listen(conf.port);           // Configure the server to port 8080

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pages'));  // All the website data is in this folder

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/pages/index.html');      // Webserver should return the page index.html
});

console.log("Server is opened: http://127.0.0.1:" + conf.port +"/\n");

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Verbunden!!!\n");
    io.sockets.emit('chat', {zeit: new Date(), name: "Server", text: "Du bist nun mit dem Server verbunden!"}); // Send Data to Client. This works
});
```

--- uart_functions.js:

```
var ioSocket = require('./start.js').io;

function TelegrammID1() {
    console.log("RUN ID 1\n");
    ioSocket.sockets.emit('chat', {zeit: new Date(), name:'Tester', text: "Das ist ein Test"}); // Send data to client - This doesn't work    
}
```

Now in the file uart_functions.js i get the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined."

I understand why the error occurs. But I do not know what and how I still have to pass over the file start.js by module.export to the file uart_functions.js

About the search I have found the following:[Cannot read property 'socket's of undefined when exporting socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875470/cannot-read-property-sockets-of-undefined-when-exporting-socket-io)

Unfortunately there was no useful answer.
**Thanks for your help**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are requiring `ioSocket` outside the function `TelegrammID1` which is again exported to run when a conection is made. Define the variable `ioSocket` inside the function `TelegrammId1` and make sure you export that function.

```
 function TelegrammID1() {
   var ioSocket = require('./start.js').io;
   console.log("RUN ID 1\n");
   ioSocket.sockets.emit('chat', {zeit: new Date(), name:'Tester', text: "Das ist ein Test"}); // Send data to client - This doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Amazing! @Rohith, I would never imagine that would cause an issue. Worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you're doing the right way. Export it as follows

```
    // Configure the build-in webserver
    var 
      express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      server = require('http').createServer(app),
      io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
      conf = require('./serverConfig.json');

   // module.exports = server;            // Export to use with uart_functions.js

   // module.exports.io = io;             // Export to use with uart_functions.js

    server.listen(conf.port);           // Configure the server to port 8080

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pages'));  // All the website data is in this folder

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/pages/index.html');      // Webserver should return the page index.html
    });

    console.log("Server is opened: http://127.0.0.1:" + conf.port +"/\n");

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("Verbunden!!!\n");
        io.sockets.emit('chat', {zeit: new Date(), name: "Server", text: "Du bist nun mit dem Server verbunden!"}); // Send Data to Client. This works
    });

    module.exports = {
     io: io,
     server:server
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

With this Code:

```
  module.exports = 
  {
    io: io,
    server:server
  }
```

And this line in the uart_functions.js: `var ioSocket = require('./start.js');`
I geht the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

I also tried the following export:

```
module.exports = 
  {
    io: io,
    server:server,
    app: app,
    express: express
  }
```

But this returns the same error....